Mysterious light streaks on a simple mesh
I'm guessing this has been asked thousands of times but I haven't been able to find a helpful answer yet:
I'm getting strange light striping & shadows that show up at specific angles on this object. The object seems to be ok Any ideas what is causing it?





From your image it looks like bad topology and a lot of Ngons. It could also be faces overlapping. If you are using EEVEE, try to increase your shadows resolution too

it looks like an artefact created by the low-angled light?

It's a problem with the soft shadows in EEVEE (they are simply not as good as "real" shadows in Cycles). What you can do is disable Soft Shadows completely in the Render Properties (but then the lighting will of course look different), or in the Shadows options set Cube Size to 4096 px to make the streaks finer (but still ugly) or in the settings of your light set Soft Falloff > Radius to a higher value, at least 0.25 or more (then the lighting looks of course different as well). Or just set the light higher above the object so that the angle is not so low.

Awesome thank you for all the suggestions. I'll give them a try.

That all worked great, thank you @GordonBrinkmann !

@Gordon or Matthew .. I don't think this one has come up before like this, so an answer or self-answer would be better than closing out as not needing one? If one of you has a moment?

@RobinBetts Maybe later... I was hesitant to write an answer, since I avoid using EEVEE most of the time because I prefer Cycles... so I just saw my comment as workarounds until maybe someone who is more familiar with EEVEE comes up with a real solution for this (if there is one that is not just about making it less bad like my suggestions).
